# Trying to use pouchDB, saying that it's not defined when i think it is

Tags: javascript, node.js, progressive-web-apps, pouchdb

i'm trying to add pouchdb to my pwa to store some things when offline so i can post them later. I first register my Service Worker from app.js, and from it i ImportScript two other files with the logic of the sw. One of those files is where i put the logic for the db, sw_db.js. I installed pouchDB with npm and added the script tag for it in index.html but i when i declare:

```
const db = new PouchDB('acciones');
```

i get

```
sw_db.js:4 Uncaught ReferenceError: PouchDB is not defined
    at sw_db.js:4
    at sw.js:3
```

Basically, sw_db.js doesnt know about PouchDB even though the methods from pouchdb get autocompleted. i've tried adding the cdn or downloading the file but still doesnt work. Also the script tag for pouchdb is before app.js in index.html (which registers the sw).

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you are using PouchDB in a browser or a NodeJS context. If it is in a browser, then the PouchDB module should be defined in the HTML file like this:

```
<script src="js/pouchdb.min.js"></script>
```

assuming you have the PouchDB module on your web server. If not you can use it from a CDN like this:

```
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pouchdb@7.1.1/dist/pouchdb.min.js"></script>
```

and your Javascript code should work:

```
const db = new PouchDB('my-db');
```

But if it is in a NodeJS script then you need to install PouchDB with npm as you mention and declare it in the code like this:

```
const PouchDB = require('pouchdb');
```

and then define a database the same as before:

```
const db = new PouchDB('my-db');
```

I hope this helps you resolve the error.

Comment: Thank you for your response, i had tried all these though, I was triying to use it in a Service Worker. Finally i had to add ImportScript(js/pouchdb.min.js) to the SW file. Took me a while to realize that was missing though. Thank you again